# Is anyone able to tell me the language being spoken in this video?

Tags: translation

Specifically at 01:05
https://vimeo.com/5297531

I am reproducing the audio for this film as my final year study at university and am unable to work out exactly what is being said.

If anyone could tell me the language being spoken, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Cantonese. The character is naming colors, but the colors he's naming are different from the ones that appear in English on the screen. First he says "green", then he says "purple", then "red", etc.

Comment: Aah, okay, that will be why I was having trouble with attempting to translate it from English by myself, thanks so much!

Comment: @user2543 Welcome to Linguistics SE! If you think this answer satisfies you and actually *answers* the question, please consider clicking the tick mark you see on the left. FYI, in case you want to change the accepted answer in the future, you will be able to do it anytime, by clicking on the tick mark next to the answer you want to accept. :)

Comment: The boy's accent is also not standard Hong Kong Cantonese. He may not be a native speaker, or is perhaps a speaker of some other variety of Yue.